# Shuffle Chunks of a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of 90 rows and 90 columns.

My goal is to divide this data frame into 9 pieces, each with 30 rows and 30 columns. Then, I would like to randomly shuffle these 9 pieces for a new data frame.

I'm not sure how to approach this as I'm fairly new in R.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `sample` on a list of vectors, then unlist and subset:

If I understand rightly, you're trying to do something a bit like one of those 3*3 sliding picture puzzles, right? Where you split the df into chunks of 30 and then 'shuffle' those chunks. This will do that:

```r
### Create a 90 by 90 data frame
set.seed(2)
df <- as.data.frame(array(runif(90*90), dim = c(90,90)))

### Function to randomise subsetting
rand_dims <- function(){
  myDims <- list(1:30, 31:60, 61:90)
  unlist(sample(myDims))
}

### Shuffle 'chunks' of df
df[rand_dims(), rand_dims()] -> shuffled

### Checking the leading row/col names
### Shows we've succeeded 
colnames(shuffled)[1:5]
#> [1] "V61" "V62" "V63" "V64" "V65"
rownames(shuffled)[1:5]
#> [1] "31" "32" "33" "34" "35"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try the following code using `split` + `sample`, which helps shuffle the chunks

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(data = rnorm(90 * 90), ncol = 90, nrow = 90)
rrnd <- split(sample(seq(nrow(mat))), gl(3, nrow(mat) / 3))
crnd <- split(sample(seq(ncol(mat))), gl(3, ncol(mat) / 3))

mat.shuffle <- c()
for (i in rrnd) {
  for (j in crnd) {
    mat.shuffle <- c(mat.shuffle, list(mat[i, j]))
  }
}
```

---

Note that `mat.shuffle` is a list of `9` chunks. If you want to transform back to the matrix of size `90x90`, you can run the code below afterwards

```
out <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    split(
      mat.shuffle,
      gl(3, length(mat.shuffle) / 3)
    ),
    function(x) do.call(cbind, x)
  )
)
```

and you will see

```
> str(out)
 num [1:90, 1:90] -0.639 -0.984 -0.108 -0.939 1.743 ...
> str(mat.shuffle)
List of 9
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] -0.639 -0.984 -0.108 -0.939 1.743 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] -0.718 -0.154 -0.29 -0.796 1.7 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] -0.886 0.887 -0.381 0.371 0.327 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] -0.4555 -0.901 0.0312 -3.0223 0.8688 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] 0.705 1.559 -1.278 -0.676 1.933 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] -0.1916 -0.98649 -1.65769 0.00104 -0.19544 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] 1.668 -0.869 1.469 -0.222 -1.869 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] 0.9931 0.4116 1.995 -0.4456 -0.0692 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:30] -1.462 -0.206 1.197 -1.611 -1.708 ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked really well as well!